# Python Linked List Trouble

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to convert a string of numbers into a linked list of integers. For some reason when I go to print the value of each value in the linked list, it only prints the first value. For example: a string "523" would be turned into a linked list: 5->2->3, but it's only printing the first node value 5. Can someone please help me see what I am missing? Thanks for any help!

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

total = "523"
root = None
curr_node = None

for digit in total:
    if root is None:
        root = ListNode(int(digit), curr_node)
    else:
        curr_node = ListNode(int(digit))
        curr_node = curr_node.next

while root:
    print(root.val)
    root = root.next
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that assigning a new value to `curr_node` does *not* change the `None` value currently assigned to `root.next` or `curr_node.next`. Instead, you should keep a reference to the current/last node *itself*:

```
root = last = None
for digit in total:
    if root is None:
        root = last = ListNode(int(digit))
    else:
        last.next = last = ListNode(int(digit))
```

Alternatively: Creating a recursive data structure like a linked list is often easier and more "natural" using a recursive function instead of a loop:

```
def to_list(s):
    if s:
        return ListNode(int(s[0]), to_list(s[1:]))
    else:
        return None

root = to_list(total)
```

Comment: In recursive solution it's more common to pass incrementing index *([code](https://tio.run/##VY5dCgIxDITfe4qwTy0WWV0EEXsD2QuIlMXNYqCkS1tFT19b/EHzEpiZfJP5kS6eu@0ccj67IUY4UEy9H3EnoMyIE1hLTMlaGdFNGm6DM60GxnsyvWdUr2SdGlgWH0xN/cs1X/S6hKjY5K0rXTJqINO@KTQBwR4csow/4IDpGvj7myQud0c6Kf2HgQWslBIieF@7PlazWXeNyvkJ))* instead of slicing. It should demonstrate better performance as well. I'd not recommend to do it recursively though as recursion depth is limited.

Comment: thanks a lot, makes a lot of sense now Tobias! And Thanks Olvin for that additional recursion method! Much appreciated!